# Remember me Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, remember-me

I don't understand why RememberMe functionality Symfony is not supported by my user class. 
The cookie is create for 1 year (31536000s).

```
DEBUG - Remember-me cookie detected. 
WARNING - User class for remember-me cookie not supported. 
DEBUG - Clearing remember-me cookie "REMEMBERME"
```

I use FOSUserBundle with this firewall :

```
firewalls:
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        anonymous: true
        provider: main
        form_login:
            login_path: fos_user_security_login
            check_path: fos_user_security_check
            default_target_path: fos_user_profile_edit
            success_handler: redirect.after.login
            csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
            remember_me: true
        logout:
            path: fos_user_security_logout
            target: /
        remember_me:
            always_remember_me: true
            remember_me_parameter: _remember_me
            key: %secret%
            lifetime: 31536000
            path: /
            domain: ~
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem in login manager. remember_me services aren't public in SF2.3. So this code doesn't work

https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Security/LoginManager.php